# Relay Switching Causing Arduino to Crash when Load Attached to Relay

Tags: arduino, relay, interference

The title pretty much says it all

When we don't have devices attached to the relay (standard 4 relay module board) this doesn't happen. But when there are devices attached this does cause the problem and needing to reset the Arduino.

It's not even every time, but between 2-6 flips of the relay the arduino freezes.

Haven't tested this yet for proximity as an issue, and I will be trying a different 4 relay module early next week.

Just wondering if anyone has had, or heard of, this problem before? Can a relay throw off interference strong enough to cause an arduino to crash?

Comment: `Can a relay throw off interference strong enough to cause an arduino to crash?` ... that makes no sense ... you said that there are no problems when the relay is not switching a load ... the relay still switches, even without a load

Comment: Yes the relay still switches without a load, but is there potential interference happening when the ac current is passing through the relay after it switches, as opposed to switching with no ac current flowing after the switch

Answer (score 0):

A circuit diagram of what you are trying to achieve would help.
If the devices share a common power supply or possibly even a common earth wire with the Arduino then the sudden current surges as they switch on or off could be causing the problem.
I suggest, as a test, you try isolating the Arduino from the rest of the devices with a separate supply (battery?) or, at least, decoupling its power supply with, say, 100uF + 10nF capacitors inserted as close as possible.

Comment: Devices controlled by the relay should never share common ground, those are completely isolated. Yes, if the relay module is getting its 5v power delivery not from the arduino's regulator then the module and arduino should share a ground, but not the controlled devices.

Comment: Still, a circuit diagram will enable us to see the big picture.